# Check multiple conditions, then if all are false do something

Tags: powershell, logic

Bit of background...

I'm trying to write a script which will run constantly. I need to it check to see if the Queue directory has an XML file in it, if it does, then send an API call to start some servers.

I've got this part sorted and it works.

I'm having issues with the second part where I need it to send another API Call to shutdown the servers if the following conditions are met;

- Queue Directory must be empty
- Running Directory must be empty
- The time between the servers starting and stopping must be to the nearest hour (its AWS so they charge by the hour, there's no point in stopping a server if its only been running for a few mins as we'll still be charged for the full hour. Then if we need to start again, we'll be charged another hour.)

Here is what I have so far:

```
$QueueDir = "D:\Test"
$RunningDir = "D:\Test\copydir"
while (!(Test-path $QueueDir\*.xml)) {Start-Sleep 10}
Write-Host "Starting Servers, API NORMALLY GOES HERE"
$Starttime = (Get-Date)
Write-Host "Started Servers @ $Starttime"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

while (!(Test-Path $rundir\*.xml)) {Start-Sleep 10}
$now = (Get-Date)
$timespan = (New-TimeSpan -Start $Starttime -End $now)
if ( (Test-Path $QueueDir\*.xml) -or (Test-Path $RunningDir\*.xml) -or ($timespan.Minutes -gt 50 -and -lt 55) ) {
  Write-Host "Stopping Servers, API NORMALLY GOES HERE"
  $StopTime = (Get-Date)
  Write-Host "Stopped Servers @ $Stoptime"
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem or 'issues'?

Comment: im not entirely sure what is happening, im pretty sure i've got the logic wrong in the second chunk of code.
When i run it, it never shuts the servers down

Comment: What I suggest, is you place `write-host`  at every stage of your second loop to get a visual feedback of where the code is never hitting. i.e. does it ever get to your API call code? once you find the exact area in question, you'll have a much better time debugging it.

Comment: OK Thanks. So from a 'fresh set of eyes' point of view you cant see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing blazing me the face, but I would most defiantly get some visual feedback while your testing to find the exact area of which your script is failing.

Comment: OK great, I'll do some more testing and report back if that's OK?

Answer (score 3):

This `$timespan.Minutes -gt 50 -and -lt 55` is not valid PowerShell logic. You have to provide a value expression after `-and`. You would receive an error like this:

> You must provide a value expression following the '-and' operator.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

So you would need to use it like:

```
$timespan.Minutes -gt 50 -and $timespacn.Minutes -lt 55
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's simple [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra). You want to take action if neither of three conditions is true. That can be formulated like this:

```
!A ^ !B ^ !C     # (not A) and (not B) and (not C)
```

The above can be transformed as follows (`(!A ^ !B) ⇔ !(A v B)`), since multiple negations in an expression tend to be ugly:

```
!(A v B v C)     # not (A or B or C)
```

In your code that would look like this:

```
if (-not ((Test-Path ...) -or (Test-Path ...) -or ($timespan.Minutes ...))) {
  ...
}
```